# Create a list of videos like Instagram/Vine... on Android

Tags: android, list, video, instagram, vine

I'm working on a project where I need to create a list of videos like Instagram or Vine (where the videos are played automatically while you are scrolling). I've searched but I can't find the exact way that they are doing that on these apps that i mentioned. Hope someone can give me a clue or something.

Answer (score 2):

you can try using [Toro Library](https://github.com/eneim/Toro), which solves it very nicely with recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Look into creating a vertical ListView of VideoViews.